# Filter Object passed on Value Properties

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this:

```
let obj = {'machine1':{'err':'404', switch:false},
           'gadget1':{'err':'404', switch:true}}

Would not pass validation. => return false



let obj2 = {'machine2':{'err':'404', switch:false},
           'gadget2':{'err':null, switch:true}}

Would pass validation. => return true
```

I want to return true when every key in the object in which the switch is set to true does not have any errors (see obj2). (For machine2 the '404' error does not matter, because the switch is set to false.)

I tried something like that, but didn't get far.

```
function try() { 
  for (x in obj) {
    obj[x].filter(x=>y.switch === true)
}
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like the follow:

```
const test = obj => Object.keys(obj).every(k => !obj[k].switch || obj[k].err === null)
```

So you check if `every` key in the object has `switch` set to false or the `err` equal to null.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by usign `entries` and `every` helpers of `Array`, like this:

```js
let obj = {
  'machine1': {
    'err': '404',
    switch: false
  },
  'gadget1': {
    'err': '404',
    switch: true
  }
}

let obj2 = {
  'machine2': {
    'err': '404',
    switch: false
  },
  'gadget2': {
    'err': null,
    switch: true
  }
};
const validate = (data) => {
  return Object.entries(data).every(([key, value]) => !value.switch || value.err === null)
}

console.log(validate(obj));
console.log(validate(obj2));
```

Comment: The check statement can be simplified removing `value.switch == true &&`, especially if you do a loose equality check with `false` (if a value is not falsy, then it must be truthy, except with `NaN` I think).

Comment: RIght, I edited my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like that?

```
let obj={
    1:{
        'machine':{'err':'404', switch:false},
        'gadget':{'err':'404', switch:true}
    },
    2:{
        'machine':{'err':'404', switch:false},
        'gadget':{'err':null, switch:true}
    }
}
```

I changed the facility a bit to make it easier.

```
var n=1;
while (n<=2) {

if(obj[n].machine.switch==true){
    if(obj[n].machine.err!='404')
       console.log('SUKCES')
    else console.log('ERROR 1')
}
else console.log('ERROR 0')

if(obj[n].gadget.switch==true){
    if(obj[n].gadget.err!='404')
       console.log('SUKCES')
    else console.log('ERROR 1')
}
else console.log('ERROR 0')
n++;
}
```

Results:

> ERROR 0
>
> ERROR 1
>
> ERROR 0
>
> SUKCES